# Use of undefined constant HOST, USER, PASS, DBSA error?

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I´m having a problem and dont understand why is happening...

This Way works fine:

```
<?php


    $conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die ('Error connection<strong>'.mysql_error().'</strong>');
    $dbsa = mysql_select_db('project') or die ('Error selecting bd:   <strong>'.mysql_error().'</strong>');

?>
```

Why this Way gives an error:

```
<?php

        define(HOST,'localhost');
        define(USER,'root');
        define(PASS,'');
        define(DBSA,'project');

        $conn = mysql_connect(HOST,USER,PASS) or die ('Error connection<strong>'.mysql_error().'</strong>');
        $dbsa = mysql_select_db(DBSA) or die ('Error selecting bd:   <strong>'.mysql_error().'</strong>');

    ?>
```

ERROS:

Notice: **Use of undefined constant HOST - assumed 'HOST'** in F:\Xampp\htdocs\project\bd\connect.php on line 2

Notice: **Use of undefined constant USER - assumed 'USER'** in F:\Xampp\htdocs\project\bd\connect.php on line 3

Notice: **Use of undefined constant PASS - assumed 'PASS'** in F:\Xampp\htdocs\project\bd\connect.php on line 4

Notice: **Use of undefined constant DBSA - assumed 'DBSA'** in F:\Xampp\htdocs\project\bd\connect.php on line 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to surround your [**definied**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) constants with quotes

```
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','root');
define('PASS','');
define('DBSA','project');
```

Now you can call them without quotes

```
$conn = mysql_connect(HOST,USER,PASS) or die ('Error connection<strong>'.mysql_error().'</strong>');
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! I didn´t know that was necessary '' in constants! The documentation that I saw used without '', maybe is old documentation! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for define is

```
define('CONSTANT_NAME', 'SOME VALUE');
```